# Rotation failed in Java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I develop a program to make a simulator of a Rubiks Cube 2x2x2. 
And now I have to develop the rotation, it works one by one.

But when I make 2 rotation in a row a problem rise.

```
public void rotate() { 
    Matrix3d oldRot = new Matrix3d();
    Vector3d oldPos = new Vector3d();

    Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
    getTransform(tr);
    tr.get(oldRot, oldPos);

    matPos.transform(oldPos);

    System.out.println("oldRot : ");
    System.out.println(oldRot);

    oldRot.mul(matRot);
    setTransform(new Transform3D(oldRot, oldPos, 1));
}

public void setupRotation(char charAxis, double angle, double totalAngle) {
    matPos = null;
    matRot = null;
    Vector3d currentAxis = new Vector3d();
    if (charAxis == 'y') {
        double sin = Math.sin(angle);
        double cos = Math.cos(angle);
        matPos = new Matrix3d(cos, 0, -sin, 0, 1, 0, sin, 0, cos);
        currentAxis = ay;
    } else if (charAxis == 'x') {
        double sin = Math.sin(-angle);
        double cos = Math.cos(-angle);
        matPos = new Matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, cos, -sin, 0, sin, cos);
        currentAxis = ax;
    } else if (charAxis == 'z') {
        double sin = Math.sin(-angle);
        double cos = Math.cos(-angle);
        matPos = new Matrix3d(cos, -sin, 0, sin, cos, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        currentAxis = az;
    }

    AxisAngle4d axis = new AxisAngle4d(currentAxis.x, currentAxis.y,currentAxis.z, -angle);
    Transform3D rot = new Transform3D();

    rot.setRotation(axis);

    matRot = new Matrix3d();
    rot.get(matRot);
}
```

The result have to be a rotation of 4 square together

Actually, if I rotate the left side and after the top side, 2 of the 4 square will rotate together but the 2 other which where on the left side before seems to rotate on 2 axis

Comment: Are you trying to rotate one side of a Rubik's cube, like a person attempting to solve the puzzle, or are you just trying to rotate a 3D object in space?

Comment: I'm trying to rotate one side to solve it